# Making GPRS Connection programmatically using C# for windows CE 5.0?

Tags: c#, connection, windows-ce, gprs

I'm new to Windows CE so tack it easy.
  I want to create a GPRS connection pragmatically and dial it in C# for windows CE 5.0 (Visual Stdio 2008). I searched a lot more that 100 pages but nothing!!! for example :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb840031.aspx

For connecting GPRS I have to dial *99# and some settings but I don't know how to use these sample codes with my settings. The connection management tacks no settings or I do not know how.

Is there any sample code to create GPRS connection with desire settings and dial it?
And also I need to dial USSD code request and get response. Is it possible?
I have OpenNetCF.dll and ... 
I highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

please check out my question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748351/dialing-ras-from-wince-device#comment20643447_14748351).
I already have a solution, which should work, just stuck on a problem. Maybe you can step over it. In this case, I will be happy, if you can help me.

You can download OpenNETCF from [here](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework.aspx).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help but what is assembly reference for "RasDialParams"? It can not finded and also "Ras" in Ras.CreateEntry?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, forgot to include one more link: http://rascf.codeplex.com/ - here you can find extended OpenNetCF