# Dialing RAS from WinCE device

Tags: c#, windows-ce, gprs, ras

I am working on a bigger project, which part is to create software for Motorola MC9596 scanner, but I am stuck with datatransmission trough GPRS mobile connection using FTP server.

For this purpose I am using OpenNETCF.

The problem is that I cannot dial connection with entry I created. That means there are 2 entries in device's phonebook, test1 - generated by device, when I configured connection on device manually and test2, which was created programatically using:

```
private const string CONNAME = "test2";
private const string PHONENR = "~GPRS!xxx.xxx-xxxxxxxx.eu";
private const string USER = "xx";
private const string PWD = "xx";
private const string DEVICE_TYPE = "modem";
private const string DEVICE_NAME = "Cellular Line";

private void createConnectionEntry()
{
    RasEntry rasEnt = new RasEntry()
    {
        Name = CONNAME,
        CountryCode = 0,
        AreaCode = "",
        PhoneNumber = PHONENR,
        DeviceName = DEVICE_NAME,
        DeviceType = DEVICE_TYPE,
        IPAddress = "0.0.0.0",
        IPAddressDns = "0.0.0.0"
    };

    /*rasEnt.Options |= (int)ConnectionOptions.UseCountryAndAreaCodes;
    rasEnt.Options |= (int)ConnectionOptions.UseLogonCredentials;*/
    rasEnt.Options = 4194304;

    RasDialParams dialParams = new RasDialParams()
    {
        UserName = USER,
        Password = PWD,
    };

    cEntry = Ras.CreateEntry(rasEnt, dialParams);
}
```

Note "rasEnt.Options = 4194304", what was hardcoded, to have exact copy of settings generated by device by configuring connection manually.
Strange is, that if I compare 2 entries in debug mode, both are equal - that means all properties are equal, the only difference is Name. I am sure about this, used also reflection, to compare objects.

I dial connection with:

```
RasError re = cEntry.Dial(false, new RasDialParams(CONNAME, USER, PWD));
```

In case Test1 I get "success", in case of Test2 "unknown" error.

Could you please help me with that nasty problem?

Comment: Where's the APN in your settings?

Comment: I added more details to source code.

Comment: What happens if you delete test1 and test2, then re-create ONLY test2?  Does test2 work then?

Comment: If I recreate it programatically, it does not work. If manually trough device, it is OK.

Comment: Delete both tests, then re-create the test programmatically. Now open Hyperterminal (or similar), connected to your modem port. Type ATI to check that you are looking at the modem, then AT+CPIN="your pin" to unlock the SIM, then use AT+CGDCONT? to see exactly which PDP contexts are on your device. Is it the same when you create the test manually?

Comment: Okay, I will try it, one more info meantime, which may help: if I create entry programatically, I do not see it between manually created ones on device but I can retrieve it programatically. Also, when I delete manual entry programatically, it seems to be, that only settings are deleted, entry remains here.

Comment: Well, I am stuck on first step - how can I start Hyperterminal to have it connected to modem port and which free available hyperterminal can I use for this?

Comment: You can download Hyperterminal free from the internet (I'm not sure if it is the best for Windows CE though).  To find the modem port, look in Windows Device Manager, find "modems", right click on your device and choose "properties".  There, you should see the modem port.

Comment: Any program that allows you to send AT commands will do.  What I am thinking is, that you need to see what connections are actually configured by your software on the device.  The device can store up to 16 connections side by side, and you can see them with AT+CGDCONT?.  It may be, that you need to configure always connection number 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I ended with adding necessary registry entries manually - just checked difference in registry before and after creating connection. Not a clean solution, but did not find other one. It seems to be working stable, I can dial connection created this way. I will see, if it is OK in productive phase.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is to dial through code: While i was trying i faced other issues. Though above code from Hogo, helped a lot but there are few tips that would be useful for hassle free coding:

**First of all the following tips requires you dial your connection manually and test your internet by running any website on your internet explorer. If internet is working then you are good to go dialing it through code.**

**To do it manually:**

Make a new connection named "GPRS" using "Network and Dial up Connections"(use this link: http://www.e-consystems.com/gprs.asp). If you are using airtel SIM change baudarate from 19200 to 115200. Connect it and check if internet is working.

**Dialing through code:**

1. When you create a connection named "GPRS" manually, 3 registers are made under GPRS folder. (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Comm\RasBook\GPRS) . these folders cannot be viewed normally. Requires application to be installed in PDA that read registers.There is no need to see whats inside, if you do then download them according to the windows versions.
2. Out of 3 registers created only two of them are relevant (DevCfg and Entry). Once you have dialed and connected to internet manually, copy data from DevCfg and Entry registers to a text file (DevCfg.txt and Entry.txt) so that later you could copy back these values. To copy to/from registers to text file use: RegQueryValueEx(...), RegOpenKeyEx(..),RegSetValueEx(...) and other relevant functions  (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For example: 
Read Register and Write to text file:

```
public static bool ReadRegString(IntPtr hKey, string lpszSubKey, string lpValueName)
    {
        try
        {
            string str = "";
            byte[] lpData = new byte[684];
            uint lpcbValue = 684;
            uint dwType = Utils.REG_BINARY;
            IntPtr phkResult = new IntPtr();
            Utils.RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, lpszSubKey, 0, 0, ref phkResult);
            if (phkResult != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                int x = Utils.RegQueryValueEx(phkResult, lpValueName, 0, ref dwType, lpData, ref lpcbValue);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < 684; i++)
                {
                    if (i != 683)
                        sb.Append(lpData[i].ToString() + "|");
                    else
                        sb.Append(lpData[i].ToString());
                }
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter outfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath))
                {
                    outfile.Write(sb.ToString());
                }
                Utils.RegCloseKey(phkResult);
        }
     }

if (Utils.ReadRegString(Utils.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, @"Comm\RasBook\GPRS", "DevCfg"))
        {
            textBoxSysVers.Text = "Succeeded Make Text File.";

        }
```

3. Now to dial through code make we use of RasEntry( add neccessary libraries ; check answer of Hogo in [Making GPRS Connection programmatically using C# for windows CE 5.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736416/making-gprs-connection-programmatically-using-c-sharp-for-windows-ce-5-0))

a) create RasEntry object

b) Copy data from text file created "Entry.txt and DevCfg.txt"
 to registers Entry and DevCfg repectively.

c) Dial RasError re = cEntry.Dial(...)

For exmaple:

```
 private const string CONNAME = "GPRS";
    private const string PHONENR = "*99#";
    private const string USER = "xx";
    private const string PWD = "xx";
    private const string DEVICE_TYPE = "modem";
    private const string DEVICE_NAME = "Cellular Line";

 { RasEntry cEntry = new RasEntry()
    {
        Name = CONNAME,
        CountryCode = 91,
        AreaCode = "120",
        PhoneNumber = PHONENR,
        DeviceName = DEVICE_NAME,
        DeviceType = DEVICE_TYPE,
        IPAddress = "0.0.0.0",
        IPAddressDns = "0.0.0.0",Options=4194304
    };

        RasDialParams dialParams = new RasDialParams()
        {
            UserName = USER,
            Password = PWD,
            EntryName = CONNAME,
            Domain = " "
        }

        if (Utils.WriteRegValue(Utils.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, @"Comm\RasBook\GPRS", "DevCfg","Entry",3))
        {
            RasError re = cEntry.Dial(false, new RasDialParams(CONNAME, USER, PWD));

            RasError rs = re;
            textBoxInfo.Text = re.ToString() + " : Dial Status";
            if(rs.ToString()=="Success")
            textBoxInfo.Text = cEntry.Status.State.ToString() + " : Dial Status";
        }
  }

public static Boolean WriteRegValue(IntPtr hKey, string lpszSubKey, string lpValueName1, string lpValueName1,uint dwType)
    {
        int iOper = 1;
        filePath = @"`enter code here`\DevCfg.txt";
        IntPtr phkResult = new IntPtr();
        Utils.RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, lpszSubKey, 0, 0, ref phkResult);
        if (phkResult == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            int iSecurity = 0;
            int dwDisp = 0;
            RegCreateKeyEx(hKey, lpszSubKey, 0, null, 0, 0, ref iSecurity, ref phkResult, ref dwDisp);
        }
        if (phkResult != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[684];
            string[] text = new string[684];
            using (System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                text = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split('|');
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 684; i++)
            {
                bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToInt32(text[i]));
            }
            iOper = Utils.RegSetValueEx(phkResult, lpValueName1, 0, dwType, bytes, (uint)bytes.Length);
            Utils.RegCloseKey(phkResult);
```

}
            }

// SImilary do it from lpValueName2

}}

The difference between hogo's code and this is that RasEntry is not getting created here. It is fed from Registers. I faced difficulties while creating object and hence the suggestion. Hope it helps :)